# Html 5 Video player. Audio only option

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

Hey I build website for mobiles with Html5 video player
I want to give option to change from video mode to audio mode
for bandwidth problems

for example:

```
            <video id='video1' controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
                <source src="http://mp3.example.com/audio.mp3", type="audio/mp3">
                <source src="http://mp4.meirtv.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
```

How to switch the sources

or any other solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let the user choose, you can make use of one audio and one video element and simply switch between them on, e.g. a button press or quality selection from a menu, etc. To sync both streams, the [current time attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp) of the elements can be used.

However, a more state of the art solution is using [adaptive streaming technologies](http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/What-Is-.../What-is-Adaptive-Streaming-75195.aspx), like [Youtube, Netfilx](http://www.dash-player.com/blog/2015/02/the-status-of-mpeg-dash-today-and-why-youtube-and-netflix-use-it-in-html5/) and an increasing number of VoD platforms are using.